# DOSbox CDROM drive permissions issue

Tags: technical-issues, dosbox, capitalism

I am currently trying to play Capitalism from a CD, on DOSBox 0.74, on Windows 10.

I mount the C: drive with:

```
MOUNT C C:\DOSC
```

Where `DOSC` is a Directory in my Windows 10 C: drive. I also mount my LG removable CD-ROM drive with:

```
MOUNT D E:\ -t cdrom
```

Where E is the CD drive in windows 10.

However, whenever I try to install from the CD, it says it does not have proper permissions within DOSBox to copy the executable to the C: drive. I have tried changing the permissions of both the DOSbox application, and the folders it interacts with on my hard drive. But, I can not figure out how to change the permissions for the CD drive itself, which may be the cause. A solution to that, or any other solution, is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried copying the contents of the CD-ROM to a folder on your hard drive and mounting that instead?  Not a solution per-se but a possible work around?